# React checkbox does not set it state to checked on label click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem that my custom checkbox does not work, 
im not very familliar with React, and can't find any nice spot to learn it more either. Can you checkout my code and tell me what i did wrong ?

```
    import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';

class Checkbox extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.checkbox = React.createRef();
    this.handleClick = () => {
      this.checkbox.current.click();
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({'checked' : this.props.checked});
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({'checked' : !this.state.checked});
  }

  render() {
    let {
      className,
      label,
      ...attributes
    } = this.props;

    const classes = classNames(
      'checkbox',
      className,
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes}>
        <input id="checkbox_1" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleChange} {...attributes} ref={this.checkbox} />
        <label for="checkbox_1" className="checkbox-label" onClick={this.handleClick}>{label}</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Checkbox.defaultProps = {
  checked: false,
  className: '',
  label: null
};

Checkbox.propTypes = {
  checked: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  label: PropTypes.string
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Problem is that this component does not get checked, but if i set state to true it does not uncheck, if i install a console log to either handleChange or handleClick, i get console.logged when i click, but only for the first click, im not sure what it means. In another post here i red that it could be problem where on click i check and uncheck so i create an infinite loop, but in that case i should have an infinite loop of console.logs i think.
If my code is totally wrong feel free to edit it as you wish, but if its not to much of a hustle try to comment for me changed parts so i better understand whats  going on :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommended tutorial series for React: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxIDLw0M-m0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ij8CfkAY2RAGb-tmkNwQHG

Comment: It looks like you solved the problem already, but I've explained why some of the weird things are happening in my answer. Check it out :)

Comment: Yes thaks, that is what i needed too, someone that can clarify some things, many thanks for that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow :)

I think your problem lies in

```
handleChange() {
  this.setState({'checked' : this.state.checked});
}
```

You're not changing the state but simply want to set it again with the same value. You should be fine when you change it to:

```
handleChange() {
  this.setState({'checked' : !this.state.checked});
}
```

EDIT:

So the real problem about the input not changing from checked to unchecked is handing over `{...attributes}` to the input. This seems to be linked to the "checked" property which interferes with the default checked value of the input element.

Moreover you should use the `htmlFor` attribute instead of `for` when working with react.

Comment: Hmm it seems that didn't fixed the problem, i will edit my question to not confuse ither people :D

Comment: I applied your things to my code and now i see when i show my checkbox ( its hidden so i can style it my way ) i can check it and it works properly, now i need to link it properly to label so it will check on label click :D I will tryo to figure it out, but i would apriciate if you could share some info on that too :D

Comment: I discovered following thing
When i click label it does not check, but it toggles checking (if label is checked i cant check checkbox)
So we are onto something, also when i check chackbox,label(thaht is styled to be chackbox) alse interacts(css changes for label:checked)

Comment: I got it to work, thanks i deleted htmlFor from label and it worked correctly

Comment: @PatrykGąsior check out my answer - you don't actually have to delete `htmlFor`, you can use it to replace the `onClick` event, which is cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Problem number one is that you are setting a default prop `checked: false` in `defaultProps`, and this prop is always being set on the `input` via `{...attributes}`, so you're effectively always writing that value to false, which is why state changes aren't making any difference.

To fix, you can either get rid of that default prop (and also get rid of setting the state in `componentDidMount`), or you could stop throwing all `attributes` data into the `input` element by default. Up to you.

Now you should be able to see the checkbox get checked / unchecked.

As for changing the property `for` to `htmlFor` on the `label` element, this actually will basically bind the `label` element to the `input`, so you won't have to implement the `onClick` handler for the `label`. So once you fix this property, just get rid of your `onClick` on the `label` entirely. Here's the final code:

All in all, here's what to change:

1. Remove `{...attributes}` from the `<input>` element **or** remove `checked` from `defaultProps`
2. Change the `for` property to `htmlFor` on the `<label>` element
3. Remove the `onClick` event from the `<label>` element

Comment: Thanks for information provided, but as go for number 2 i tested this solution and i belive its not wise to use it in component. Let me explain why ( correct me if im wrong ), when i use 2 of these i need to assign them with not identical ids like checkbox-1 checkbox-2 etc.
Well i don't see a problem in this, that can be made dynamiclly, but for now i don't think that its important to me :D maybe later when i will optimize things i will think about that solution

Comment: @PatrykGąsior if you're worried about needing to hard-code the matching `id` in the `<input>` elem / `htmlFor` in the `<label>` elem, I'd recommend one of two solutions: 1) Pass that value as a prop, so the parent component would pass `identifier={'checkbox-1'}`, then use `this.props.identifier` in both the `<input>` and `<label>` components

Comment: Option 2: In your `Checkbox` class component, when initializing state, create a random string (or random number) then attach that to a string, like: `this.state = {checked: false, identifier: 'checkbox-' + ~~(Math.random() * 10000) }`, then use `this.state.identifier` in your `<input>` and `<label>` components.

Comment: @PatrykGąsior in option #2 you won't have to think about passing anything to your `Checkbox` components, they'll automatically sync up. In option #1 you will, so you'd probably have to set that prop as required via `PropTypes`. Thoughts?

Comment: This is the clearest answer and fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is also an HTML problem, you have to link the label with the input so they trigger together, see solution below, also this might help (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

```html
<h1>checkbox demo</h1>

<input type="checkbox">
<label>I don't activate the checkbox</label>

<hr>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1">
<label for="checkbox_1">I activate the checkbox</label>

<hr>

<label>
 <input type="checkbox">
 I also activate the checkbox
</label>
```

Comment: i guess that wasn't it, problem still occurs, i will edit my question with your solution aswell.